# Multiple models in a queryset and/or multiple serializers for one View?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I have a `Foo` model and a `Bar` model:

```
# models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_title = CharField()
   
class Bar(models.Model):
    bar_title = CharField()


# serializers.py
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ["foo_title"]

class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ["bar_title"]
```

If I want to return a `Foo` and a `Bar` model, I have to set up and call two views:

```
# urls.py
path("foo/<pk>/", FooView.as_view())
path("bar/<pk>/", BarView.as_view())

# views.py
class FooView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    lookup_field = pk

class BarView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BarSerializer
    lookup_field = pk
```

And then combine the two data results on my front-end.

Is it possible to create one `View` that has multiple models in the queryset and/or multiple serializers? How can I make only one call to my API backend to return the data of different serializers with different models?

e.g. Something like

```
# urls.py
path("foobar/<foo_pk>/<bar_pk>", FoobarView.as_view())

# views.py
class FoobarView(generics.ListAPIView):
    pass
```

Comment: What problem do you have with calling two APIs to get the two unrelated pieces of data?

Comment: @IainShelvington My actual use case involves GenericForeignKeys so the different models are related. I specifically would like to save an additional prefetching query if I can group the multiple pieces of data together.

I could also use ForeignKeys as a more simple example. ```Ingredient``` Cheese is an ingredient in both ```Sandwich``` Cheeseburger and ```Pizza``` CheesePizza. How can I return one View that returns the ```Ingredient```, the ```Sandwich```s, and the ```Pizza```s?

Comment: So you’re querying by Ingredient (cheese) and want to return all related sandwiches and pizzas? Can you update the question to contain this model structure with the generic foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this via APIView:

```
# urls.py
path("foobar/<foo_pk>/<bar_pk>", FoobarView.as_view())

# views.py
class FoobarView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, foo_pk, bar_pk):
        foo = FooSerializer(Foo.objects.get(pk=foo_pk)).data
        bar = BarSerializer(Bar.objects.get(pk=bar_pk)).data
        return Response([foo, bar], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Please don't return a list object, wrap the data in an object: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/return-a-jsonresponse-with-safe-false.html

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. Great site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

```
pip install drf-nested-routers
```

Here's an example of use:
https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers#infinite-depth-nesting